# Auto-delete empty item in listobx?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `listbox` that keep creating empty items due to appending text from a `textbox` that reads a text file .

Could I have it just remove any empty items on startup?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no setting for that.  You could of course write code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove empty items form your listbox in startup of loading
the form so use `Form1_Load` Event

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Then add this code in this event

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (ListBox1.Items.Count) - 1 >= i
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListBox1.Items(i)) Then
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items(i))
                i -= 1
            End If
            i += 1
        Loop
```

you can replace if condition statement
`String.IsNullOrEmpty(ListBox1.Items(i))`
 with 
`ListBox1.Items(i) = String.Empty`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to just filter out the empty lines when you're reading the file. If that's not possible, though:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To yourListBox.Items.Count - 1
    If CStr(yourListBox.Items(i)) = String.Empty Then
        yourListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        i -= 1
    End If
Next
```

If you are in control of the adding, then assuming you're adding them something like this:

```
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(somefile)
    yourListBox.Items.Add(line)
Next
```

... then here you go:

```
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(somefile)
    If line <> String.Empty Then yourListBox.Items.Add(line)
Next
```

Comment: The text from the text file is added to a textbox and the text from the textbox is added to the listbox. I think the problem is  accuring because the text is being appended and adding a new line to the textbox and the blank line in the textbox creates a blank item for the listbox. Thank you but none of your codes have helped.

Comment: You have error in your code, replace `Length` with `Count`.

Comment: No problem :)­­